# Python case insensitive dictionary

Tags: python, performance, beginner, python-3.x

This is a Python case insensitive dictionary that is ordered and has integer indexes for the keys and values.

I just wrote it today.

It is ordered because I am using Python 3.9.6 and plain `dict` is already ordered by default.

It prevents case insensitive duplicate keys from entering the dictionary (e.g. if 'Adele' is already in the dictionary, there can't be another key named 'adele'), and access the keys case insensitively, and updates existing key with same lowercase if found, preserves the cases of the keys when they are first inserted, and finally, it uses lists to index the keys and values.

The code:

```py
class UDict(dict):
    @staticmethod
    def _key(k):
        return k.lower() if isinstance(k, str) else k
    
    @classmethod
    def fromkeys(cls, keys, val=None):
        dic = cls()
        for i in keys:
            dic[i] = val
        return dic
    
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(UDict, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.KEYS = dict()
        self.Keys = list()
        self.Values = list()
        if self.keys():
            for k in list(self.keys()):
                v = super(UDict, self).pop(k)
                self.__setitem__(k, v)
    
    def _delete(self, key):
        k = UDict._key(key)
        self.KEYS.pop(k)
        i = self.Keys.index(k)
        self.Keys.pop(i)
        self.Values.pop(i)
    
    def _get_key(self, key):
        k = UDict._key(key)
        if k in self.KEYS:
            key = self.KEYS[k]
        return key
    
    def _process(self, key, val, modify=True):
        k = UDict._key(key)
        if k not in self.KEYS:
            self.KEYS.update({k: key})
            self.Keys.append(k)
            self.Values.append(val)
        else:
            key = self.KEYS[k]
            if modify:
                i = self.Keys.index(k)
                self.Values[i] = val
        return key
    
    def __contains__(self, key):
        key = self._get_key(key)
        return super(UDict, self).__contains__(key)
    
    def __delitem__(self, key):
        key = self._get_key(key)
        if key in self:
            self._delete(key)
            super(UDict, self).__delitem__(key)
    
    def __getitem__(self, key):
        key = self._get_key(key)
        if key in self:
            return super(UDict, self).__getitem__(key)
    
    def __setitem__(self, key, val):
        key = self._process(key, val)
        super(UDict, self).__setitem__(key, val)
    
    def at(self, i: int):
        if i not in range(len(self)):
            return None
        k = self.Keys[i]
        key = self.KEYS[k]
        val = self.Values[i]
        return (key, val)
    
    def clear(self):
        super(UDict, self).clear()
        self.KEYS.clear()
        self.Keys.clear()
        self.Values.clear()
    
    def copy(self):
        return UDict(self.items())
    
    def get(self, key, *args, **kwargs):
        key = self._get_key(key)
        if key in self:
            return super(UDict, self).get(key, *args, **kwargs)
        return None
    
    def index(self, key):
        k = UDict._key(key)
        if k not in self.KEYS:
            return None
        return self.Keys.index(k)
    
    def key_at(self, i: int):
        if i not in range(len(self)):
            return None
        k = self.Keys[i]
        return self.KEYS[k]
    
    def multiget(self, keys=None):
        if not keys:
            return None
        return [self.get(i) for i in keys]
    
    def multipop(self, keys):
        if not keys:
            return None
        for i in keys:
            self.pop(i)
    
    def pop(self, key, *args, **kwargs):
        key = self._get_key(key)
        if key in self:
            self._delete(key)
            return super(UDict, self).pop(key, *args, **kwargs)
        return None
    
    def popitem(self):
        self.KEYS.popitem()
        self.Keys.pop(-1)
        self.Values.pop(-1)
        return super(UDict, self).popitem()
    
    def setdefault(self, key, val=None):
        key = self._process(key, val, False)
        return super(UDict, self).setdefault(key, val)
    
    def update(self, obj=None):
        if not obj:
            return None
        
        if isinstance(obj, dict):
            obj = obj.items()
        
        for key, val in obj:
            key = self._process(key, val)
            super(UDict, self).update({key: val})
    
    def value_at(self, i: int):
        if i not in range(len(self)):
            return None
        return self.Values[i]
```

I have properly overridden all key related methods to make it behave exactly as I wanted it to, everything works as intended and I do need to get integer indexes.

Actually I implemented a function to get keys from values, by using the index of value in the `Values` list, but since values can be non-unique and Python lists only return indexes of first occurrences I removed it.

It is fully functional but performance wise it is considerably slower than plain `dict`s.

How can it be faster?

---

Update: Bugfix, because using `type()` on an object of `UDict` will probably return `__main__.UDict`, therefore it isn't `dict` and passing `UDict` object as argument to `.update()` method and my code will not work properly (though I seriously don't know why anyone would do that), by using `isinstance(obj, dict)` UDict objects will be treated as dict, though I really don't understand why isinstance succeeds in identifying UDict as dict.

And isinstance is somewhat faster than type, then I considered the possibility of someone subclassing str...

---

### Update

I implemented a case-insensitive `str` subclass and a dictionary subclass that automatically converts strings to case-insensitive `str`:

```py
class IStr(str):
    def __hash__(self):
        return hash(self.lower())
    
    def __eq__(self, other):
        if isinstance(other, str):
            return self.lower() == other.lower()
        return NotImplemented
    
    def __ne__(self, other):
        return not (self == other)
    
    def __lt__(self, other):
        if isinstance(other, str):
            return self.lower() < other.lower()
        return NotImplemented
    
    def __ge__(self, other):
        return not (self < other)
    
    def __gt__(self, other):
        if isinstance(other, str):
            return self.lower() > other.lower()
        return NotImplemented
    
    def __le__(self, other):
        return not (self > other)
    
    def __contains__(self, other: str):
        return other.lower() in self.lower()


class IDict(dict):
    @staticmethod
    def _key(k):
        return IStr(k) if isinstance(k, str) else k
    
    @classmethod
    def fromkeys(cls, keys, val=None):
        dic = cls()
        for i in keys:
            dic[i] = val
        return dic
    
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(IDict, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        if self.keys():
            for k in list(self.keys()):
                v = super(IDict, self).pop(k)
                self.__setitem__(k, v)
    
    def __contains__(self, key):
        key = IDict._key(key)
        return super(IDict, self).__contains__(key)
    
    def __delitem__(self, key):
        key = IDict._key(key)
        if key in self:
            super(IDict, self).__delitem__(key)
    
    def __getitem__(self, key):
        key = IDict._key(key)
        if key in self:
            return super(IDict, self).__getitem__(key)
    
    def __setitem__(self, key, val):
        key = IDict._key(key)
        super(IDict, self).__setitem__(key, val)
    
    def at(self, i: int):
        if i not in range(len(self)):
            return None
        key = list(self.keys())[i]
        val = list(self.values())[i]
        return (key, val)
    
    def copy(self):
        return IDict(self.items())
    
    def get(self, key, *args, **kwargs):
        key = IDict._key(key)
        if key in self:
            return super(IDict, self).get(key, *args, **kwargs)
        return None
    
    def index(self, key):
        k = IDict._key(key)
        if k not in self:
            return None
        return list(self.keys()).index(k)
    
    def key_at(self, i: int):
        if i not in range(len(self)):
            return None
        k = list(self.keys())[i]
        return k
    
    def multiget(self, keys=None):
        if not keys:
            return None
        return [self.get(i) for i in keys]
    
    def multipop(self, keys):
        if not keys:
            return None
        for i in keys:
            self.pop(i)
    
    def pop(self, key, *args, **kwargs):
        key = IDict._key(key)
        if key in self:
            return super(IDict, self).pop(key, *args, **kwargs)
        return None
    
    def setdefault(self, key, val=None):
        key = IDict._key(key)
        return super(IDict, self).setdefault(key, val)
    
    def update(self, obj=None):
        if not obj:
            return None
        
        if isinstance(obj, dict):
            obj = obj.items()
        
        for key, val in obj:
            key = IDict._key(key)
            super(IDict, self).update({key: val})
    
    def value_at(self, i: int):
        if i not in range(len(self)):
            return None
        return list(self.values())[i]
```

To give you some examples:

```py
from string import ascii_letters

UDict(zip(ascii_letters, range(52)))

IDict(zip(ascii_letters, range(52)))

dict(zip(map(IStr, ascii_letters), range(52)))

dict(zip(ascii_letters, range(52)))
```

The first three all give the wanted result, and the last one gives exactly what made me implement case insensitivity in the first place.

But performance wise, from multiple tests, the last one takes only about 3 microseconds to complete, while the other three, from last to first, take 30, 80 and 90 microseconds respectively.

I don't know why the custom classes are slower than `dict`, how can it be optimized?

---

And why I need a case insensitive dictionary?

This is an example:

```py
ex = [('Various Artists', 78),
 ('Two Steps From Hell', 75), 
 ('Blake Neely', 60),         
 ('Audiomachine', 59),        
 ('Bandari', 56),             
 ('Murray Gold', 46),         
 ('Secret Garden', 45),       
 ('Herbert von Karajan', 42), 
 ('Connie Talbot', 38),       
 ('Really Slow Motion', 35),  
 ('Florian Bur', 33),         
 ('Hans Zimmer', 33),         
 ('Alexandrov Ensemble', 32), 
 ('Kevin Kern', 28),          
 ('Thomas Bergersen', 28),    
 ('Brand X Music', 25)]       
                              
def fun(cls):                 
    dic = cls()               
    for k, v in ex:           
        dic[k] = v            
        dic[k.upper()] = v    
        dic[k.lower()] = v    
        dic[k.title()] = v    
        dic[k.swapcase()] = v 
    return dic
```

The strings in the tuples are artist names, the numbers are how many times they occur in the data(how many songs of them in my list).

Just run `fun(IDict)` and `fun(dict)` and you will understand.

In actual use, the dictionary will be nested, and under the artist keys are album keys and under album keys are song keys which hold the actual data (values).

The cases of the names are often inconsistent, sometimes they are in TitleCase, sometimes UPPERCASE and sometimes lowercase and only iNVALIDCASE isn't encountered, and I need the dictionary to recognize   the names as same regardless of what case they are in.

Comment: Why is this needed? Show the code that uses it and some example contents.

Comment: Does your collection (dict) have to be case insensitive? You can use case insensitive keys (custom str type) and nuke your code.

Comment: I agree with @Peilonrayz why not just use [`lower`](https://www.w3schools.com/python/ref_string_lower.asp) when comparing?

Comment: "I don't know why the custom classes are slower than `dict`". Python slow, C fast  (which `dict` is written in).

Comment: I'm going to level with you - both this question and your previous one have both code quality and question quality issues preventing meaningful review. This one in particular still doesn't demonstrate how you're actually using your song database, and is fairly theoretical. I'm not convinced that a case-insensitive, nested custom dictionary is called for, and nothing you've shown really justifies the need for custom data structure classes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**How can I make a custom data structure as fast as `dict`?**

You can't (at least, not in CPython). CPython's `dict` is written in C, as are other `dict` variants in the standard library such as `collections.defaultdict`. If you want to write custom data structures approaching the speed of a `dict`, go write it in C, Rust, or run your Python script using PyPy. Anything subclassing a `dict` becomes an object implemented in Python rather than C, so will not run nearly as fast as a `dict`.

**How can I make my code better?**

Your code at the moment is extremely confusing. Here are some of the reasons why:

1. *You don't have any docstrings.* It's really hard, as an outside reader, to understand what's going on in your code if you don't say what a specific function is for, and what its expected behaviour is. Type hints are also very helpful in this regard.
2. *You don't have any inline comments.* Similar to point (1). There's all sorts of things going on in your code *inside* functions that are frankly a little head-scratching. There's probably a really good reason for a lot of them -- so if there's something that isn't self-explanatory happening inside a function, tell us why it's happening!
3. *It's really unclear why so many of your methods are private.* What's the specific reason that the `_key` method is a private method? What would be so terrible about exposing that detail to other users? You have a *lot* of private methods, and the general expectation in Python is that a method should be public unless there's a good reason why.
4. *Your attributes are very confusingly named.* Your UDict class has one instance attribute `self.Keys`, one instance attribute `self.KEYS`, one instance method `self.keys()`, and one instance method `self._key()`. This would be bad even if they recorded similar kinds of information, but they don't! One is a `list`, one is a `dict`, one is a method that returns a `KeysView`, and one is a method that transforms an "unprocessed" key into a "processed" one. How can anybody be expected to remember the difference between all of these?! There's really nothing wrong with being a bit more verbose and giving your attributes and methods more helpful, descriptive names. Your second attempt in your question improves on this a little, but not much. Why are your classes called `IString` and `IDict`? How can anybody be expected to know what they do from their names?
5. *The motivation for your class still seems a little unclear*. You say it's a case-insensitive dict. Fine. But you *also* have added methods that will return the "integer index" of a key or value. It's unclear why these are necessary for this use case. Ditto for your `multiget` and `multipop` methods -- what are these *for*? And it's unclear why you would implement `multiget` and `multipop`, but *not* `multisetdefault` and `multipopitem`. What's the rationale here?

In addition to the above critiques, I would have started in a different place when it comes to solving this problem. My general attitude is that subclassing `dict` directly works great for when you're *extending* a `dict` -- just adding new features onto it, for a specialised purpose. But if you start *overriding* all sorts of `dict` dunder methods, I would generally look at inheriting from `collections.abc.MutableMapping` instead. The great thing about inheriting from `MutableMapping` is that by implementing just a few `abstractmethods` that `MutableMapping` has, you get a whole host of normal `dict` methods for free. In my example code below, I haven't had to override `.setdefault()`, `.pop()`, `.popitem()`, `.get()`, `.keys()`, `.values()`, `.items()`, `.clear()`, `.update()`, `__contains__()` or `.__eq__()`. They all come "for free" because I'm inheriting from `MutableMapping`. It just ends up being a lot cleaner, in my opinion.

I've also implemented a helper-class, to deal with some of the implementation-logic regarding case-insensitivity. There was just too much going on in your class, in my opinion; it made sense to shunt some of that code elsewhere.

I don't think there's a great deal of speed improvement in my refactoring below. I think in a few situations, my refactoring is a little faster than yours, but I haven't rigorously tested performance.

My code comes out as being a fair bit longer than yours, but I think the main reason for that is simply because I have a lot more comments and docstrings than you did...

```
from __future__ import annotations
from typing import Any, TypeVar, Optional, Union, NoReturn
from collections.abc import Mapping, MutableMapping, Iterator, Sequence
from abc import abstractmethod
from functools import cache


# For mapping keys and values
_K = TypeVar('_K')
_V = TypeVar('_V')

# Any subclass of _DictBoilerplateBase
_T = TypeVar('_T', bound='_DictBoilerplateBase[Any, Any]')

# For .get() defaults
_D = TypeVar('_D')


class _DictBoilerplateBase(MutableMapping[_K, _V]):
    """Base class for the mapping objects _KeyMapperDict and CaseInsensitiveDict.

    Inheriting from MutableMapping
    means the following methods are auto-implemented,
    both for this base class
    and for all classes inheriting from it:
        - .setdefault()
        - .pop()
        - .popitem()
        - .get()
        - .keys()
        - .values()
        - .items()
        - .clear()
        - .update()
        - .__contains__()
        - .__eq__()

    The following abstractmethods need to be implemented by all subclasses of this class:
        - .__init__()
        - .__getitem__()
        - .__setitem__()
        - .__delitem__()
    """

    __slots__ = 'data'
    
    data: dict[_K, _V] # For type-checkers

    @abstractmethod
    def __init__(
        self,
        data: Optional[Mapping[_K, _V]] = None,
        /,
        **kwargs
    ) -> None:
        
        if data is not None:
            self.update(data)
        if kwargs:
            self.update(kwargs)

    @classmethod
    def fromkeys(
        cls: type[_T],
        keys: Sequence[_K],
        default: Optional[_V] = None,
        /
    ) -> _T:
        """Standard alternative constructor for python mapping objects"""
        return cls({key: default for key in keys})
    
    def __iter__(self, /) -> Iterator[_K]:
        return iter(self.data.keys())
    
    def __len__(self, /) -> int:
        return len(self.data)

    def __repr__(self, /) -> str:
        return f'{type(self).__qualname__}({self.data!r})'

    def __str__(self, /) -> str:
        return f'{type(self).__name__}({self.data})'

    def __or__(self: _T, other: Mapping[_K, _V], /) -> _T:
        # (Dicts from python 3.9+ support the union operator)
        return type(self)({**self, **other})

    def __ror__(self: _T, other: Mapping[_K, _V], /) -> _T:
        # (Dicts from python 3.9+ support the union operator)
        return type(other)({**other, **self})

    def __ior__(self: _T, other: Mapping[_K, _V], /) -> _T:
        # (Dicts from python 3.9+ support the union operator)
        self.update(other)
        return self

    def copy(self: _T, /) -> _T:
        """Return a shallow copy of the mapping"""
        return type(self)(self)


class _KeyMapperDict(_DictBoilerplateBase[_K, _K]):
    """Helper class for the CaseInsensitiveDict class.

    Maps lowercase keys to the original case
    in which they were entered in the CaseInsensitiveDict.
    
    Also keeps the processed keys in a separate list,
    so that the integer index can be retrieved.

    This class knows NOTHING about the values
    in the CaseInsensitiveDict.

    All dunder methods expect to receive preprocessed keys.
    """

    __slots__ = 'keys_list'

    def __init__(
        self,
        data: Optional[Mapping[_K, _K]] = None,
        /,
        **kwargs
    ) -> None:
        # A map of lowercase-to-originalcase-keys
        self.data: dict[_K, _K] = {}
        
        # A list of the processed keys, for integer indexing
        self.keys_list: list[_K] = []

        super().__init__(data, **kwargs)

    @staticmethod
    @cache
    def process_key(key: _K, /) -> _K:
        """Normalise a key to allow for case-insensitivity when dealing with strings.
        Keys that are not strings are returned unchanged.
        """
        return key.lower() if isinstance(key, str) else key  # type: ignore[return-value]

    def register_key(
        self,
        unprocessed_key: _K,
        /
    ) -> Union[tuple[_K, int], tuple[None, None]]:
        """Determine whether a key is in the mapping, return its integer index if so.

        Parameters
        ----------
        unprocessed_key, _K:
            A key that has not yet been normalised
            according to this class's process_key method.

        Return
        ------
        If some version of the key is already in the mapping, returns (_K, int),
        a tuple consisting of:
            - The key in the form it was in
              when it was first entered in the CaseInsensitiveDict.
            - The integer index of the key in the mapping.

        If the key was not already in the mapping,
        returns:
            - (None, None)

        Examples
        --------
        >>> d = _KeyMapperDict({'spam': 'SPAM', 'eggs': 'eGgS'})
        >>> d.register_key('SPAM')
        ('SPAM', 0)
        >>> d.register_key('Eggs')
        ('eGgS', 1)
        >>> d.register_key('bacon')
        (None, None)
        """
        # This method is essentially a helper method
        # for the __setitem__ of the CaseInsensitiveDict.
        
        processed_key = self.process_key(unprocessed_key)
        
        try:
            return self[processed_key], self.keys_list.index(processed_key)
        except KeyError as err:
            self[processed_key] = unprocessed_key
            return None, None

    def __setitem__(
        self,
        processed_key: _K,
        unprocessed_key: _K,
        /
    ) -> None:
        # This method is the mirror image of __delitem__
        self.data[processed_key] = unprocessed_key
        self.keys_list.append(processed_key)

    def get_original_key(self, unprocessed_key: _K, /) -> _K:
        """Return the original key, as it was first inputted into the mapping.

        Parameters
        ----------
        unprocessed_key, _K:
            A key that has not yet been normalised
            according to this class's process_key method.

        Return
        ------
        original_key, _K:
            The equivalent key to the inputted value,
            as it was originally inputted into the mapping.

        Raises
        ------
        KeyError if no equivalent
        for the inputted key exists in this mapping.

        Example
        -------
        >>> d = _KeyMapperDict({'spam': 'SPAM', 'eggs': 'eGgS'})
        >>> d.get_original_key('SPAM')
        'SPAM'
        >>> d.get_original_key('Eggs')
        'eGgS'
        >>> d.get_original_key('bacon')
        Traceback (most recent call last):
        KeyError: 'bacon'
        """
        return self[self.process_key(unprocessed_key)]
        
    def __getitem__(self, processed_key: _K, /) -> _K:
        return self.data[processed_key]

    def remove_key(self, unprocessed_key: _K, /) -> int:
        """Delete the key from the mapping, return the index where the key used to be.

        Example
        -------
        >>> d = _KeyMapperDict({'spam': 'SPAM', 'eggs': 'eGgS', 'bacon': 'bacon'})
        >>> d.remove_key('EGGS')
        1
        >>> d
        _KeyMapperDict({'spam': 'SPAM', 'bacon': 'bacon'})
        >>> d.remove_key('Spam')
        0
        >>> d
        _KeyMapperDict({'bacon': 'bacon'})
        """
        
        # This method is essentially a helper method
        # for the __delitem__ of the CaseInsensitiveDict
        processed_key = self.process_key(unprocessed_key)
        index = self.keys_list.index(processed_key)
        del self[processed_key]
        return index
        
    def __delitem__(self, processed_key: _K, /) -> None:
        # This method is the mirror image of __setitem__
        del self.data[processed_key]
        self.keys_list.remove(processed_key)

    def index_of_key(self, unprocessed_key: _K, /) -> Optional[int]:
        """Return the "integer index" of a certain key in the keys_list.

        Parameters
        ----------
        unprocessed_key, _K:
            A key that may or may not be in the keys_list,
            and may or may not be of the same case as it was
            originally entered into the mapping.

        Return
        ------
        index, int or None:
            Either the integer index of the key in the keys_list,
            or None if the key is not in the keys_list.

        Example
        -------
        >>> d = _KeyMapperDict({'spam': 'SPAM', 'eggs': 'eGgS'})
        >>> d.index_of_key('SPAM')
        0
        >>> d.index_of_key('spam')
        0
        >>> d.index_of_key('eggs')
        1
        >>> d.index_of_key('bacon') is None
        True
        """
        processed_key = self.process_key(unprocessed_key)

        try:
            return self.keys_list.index(processed_key)
        except ValueError:
            return None

    def original_key_at_index(self, index: int, /) -> Optional[_K]:
        """Return the key at a certain integer index in the keys_list.

        Return the key as it was originally entered into the mapping,
        rather than the normalised version of the key.
        
        The keys as they were originally entered
        into the CaseInsensitiveDict
        are stored as this mapping's values.


        Parameters
        ----------
        index, int:
            An index that may or may not be valid.

        Return
        ------
        key, _K or None:
            Either the object at that integer index in the keys_list,
            or None if the integer index isn't valid.

        Example
        -------
        >>> d = _KeyMapperDict({'spam': 'SPAM', 'eggs': 'eGgS'})
        >>> d.original_key_at_index(0)
        'SPAM'
        >>> d.original_key_at_index(1)
        'eGgS'
        >>> d.original_key_at_index(5) is None
        True
        """
        try:
            return self.data[self.keys_list[index]]
        except IndexError:
            return None


class CaseInsensitiveDict(_DictBoilerplateBase[_K, _V]):
    """A case-insensitive dict.

    Where `c = CaseInsensitiveDict()`,
    `c['Adele']` returns the same value as `c['adele']` or `c['AdElE']`.
    The dict also records the integer index of the keys and values.

    The dict preserves the original case
    of the first time the key was entered into the mapping.
    E.g., it will remember that "Adele"
    as first entered into the mapping as "Adele",
    even if the value associated with "Adele" in the mapping
    is updated using the code `c['adele'] = '21'`.
    """

    __slots__ = 'keys_map', 'values_list'
    
    def __init__(
        self,
        data: Optional[Mapping[_K, _V]] = None,
        /,
        **kwargs
    ) -> None:
        
        # This is where the actual data is stored
        # It maps the UNPROCESSED keys to the values
        self.data: dict[_K, _V] = {}

        # A map of PROCESSED keys to the ORIGINAL keys
        self.keys_map: _KeyMapperDict[_K] = _KeyMapperDict()

        # A list of the key values, for integer indexing
        self.values_list: list[_V] = []

        super().__init__(data, **kwargs)

    def __setitem__(self, unprocessed_key: _K, value: _V, /) -> None:
        # (original_key, index) will be (_K, int)
        # if the key's already in the mapping.
        # Else (None, None)        
        original_key, index = self.keys_map.register_key(unprocessed_key)

        # Better to check the index,
        # as None can plausibly be used as a dictionary key
        if index is None:
            self.values_list.append(value)
            self.data[unprocessed_key] = value
        else:
            self.values_list[index] = value
            self.data[original_key] = value  # type: ignore[index]
        
    def __getitem__(self, unprocessed_key: _K, /) -> _V:
        # Catch KeyErrors and reraise them,
        # to make for a more logical traceback.
        try:
            processed_key = self.keys_map.get_original_key(unprocessed_key)
        except KeyError as err:
            raise KeyError(*err.args) from err
        else:
            return self.data[processed_key] 
        
    def __delitem__(self, unprocessed_key: _K, /) -> None:
        # Catch KeyErrors and reraise them,
        # to make for a more logical traceback.
        try:
            original_key = self.keys_map.get_original_key(unprocessed_key)
        except KeyError as err:
            raise KeyError(*err.args) from err
        else:
            del self.data[original_key]
            # the original_key is not processed -
            # the _KeyMapperDict does that for us
            self.values_list.pop(self.keys_map.remove_key(original_key))

    def index_of_key(self, unprocessed_key: _K, /) -> Optional[int]:
        """Return the integer index of a certain key in the mapping.

        This method is effectively delegated
        to the instance's `keys_map` attribute,
        which is of type `_KeyMapperDict`.

        Parameters
        ----------
        unprocessed_key, _K:
            A key that may or may not be in the mapping.

        Return
        ------
        index, int or None:
            Either the integer index of the key in the mapping,
            or None if the key is not in the mapping.

        Example
        -------
        >>> d = CaseInsensitiveDict({'a': 'spam', 'b': 'eggs'})
        >>> d.index_of_key('A')
        0
        >>> d.index_of_key('a')
        0
        >>> d.index_of_key('b')
        1
        >>> d.index_of_key('c') is None
        True
        """
        return self.keys_map.index_of_key(unprocessed_key)

    def index_of_value(self, *args: Any, **kwargs: Any) -> NoReturn:
        """Raise NotImplementedError.

        Example
        -------
        >>> d = d = CaseInsensitiveDict({'a': 'spam', 'b': 'eggs'})
        >>> d.index_of_value('spam')
        Traceback (most recent call last):
        NotImplementedError: index_of_value \
is deliberately not implemented as a method. \
Multiple values can exist in a dictionary \
that are all the same, therefore it does not make sense \
to request the index of a dictionary value.
        """
        raise NotImplementedError(
            "index_of_value is deliberately not implemented as a method. "
            "Multiple values can exist in a dictionary that are all the same, "
            "therefore it does not make sense "
            "to request the index of a dictionary value."
        )

    def index_of_item(self, *args: Any, **kwargs: Any) -> NoReturn:
        """Raise NotImplementedError.

        Example
        -------
        >>> d = d = CaseInsensitiveDict({'a': 'spam', 'b': 'eggs'})
        
        >>> d.index_of_item('a', 'spam')
        Traceback (most recent call last):
        NotImplementedError: index_of_item is deliberately not implemented. \
Use index_of_key instead.

        >>> d.index_of_item(('a', 'spam'))
        Traceback (most recent call last):
        NotImplementedError: index_of_item is deliberately not implemented. \
Use index_of_key instead.

        """
        raise NotImplementedError(
            "index_of_item is deliberately not implemented. "
            "Use index_of_key instead."
        )

    def key_at_index(self, index: int, /) -> Optional[_K]:
        """Return the key at a certain integer index in the mapping.

        Return the key as it was originally entered into the mapping,
        not the normalised version of the key.

        This method is effectively delegated
        to the instance's `keys_map` attribute,
        which is of type `_KeyMapperDict`.

        Parameters
        ----------
        index, int:
            An index that may or may not be valid.

        Return
        ------
        key, _K or None:
            Either the key at that integer index in the mapping,
            or None if the integer index isn't valid.

        Example
        -------
        >>> d = CaseInsensitiveDict({'a': 'spam', 'b': 'eggs'})
        >>> d.key_at_index(0)
        'a'
        >>> d.key_at_index(1)
        'b'
        >>> d.key_at_index(2) is None
        True
        """
        return self.keys_map.original_key_at_index(index)

    def value_at_index(self, index: int, /) -> Optional[_V]:
        """Return the value at a certain integer index in the mapping.

        Parameters
        ----------
        index, int:
            An index that may or may not be valid.

        Return
        ------
        value, _V or None:
            Either the value at that integer index in the mapping,
            or None if the integer index isn't valid.

        Example
        -------
        >>> d = CaseInsensitiveDict({'a': 'spam', 'b': 'eggs'})
        >>> d.value_at_index(0)
        'spam'
        >>> d.value_at_index(1)
        'eggs'
        >>> d.value_at_index(5) is None
        True
        """
        try:
            return self.values_list[index]
        except IndexError:
            return None

    def item_at_index(self, index: int, /) -> Optional[tuple[_K, _V]]:
        """Return the (key, value) pair at a certain integer index in the mapping.

        Parameters
        ----------
        index, int:
            An index that may or may not be valid.

        Return
        ------
        item, (_K, _V) or None:
            Either the (key, value) pair
            at that integer index in the mapping,
            or None if the integer index isn't valid.

        Example
        -------
        >>> d = CaseInsensitiveDict({'a': 'spam', 'b': 'eggs'})
        >>> d.item_at_index(0)
        ('a', 'spam')
        >>> d.item_at_index(1)
        ('b', 'eggs')
        >>> d.item_at_index(2) is None
        True
        """
        key = self.key_at_index(index)
        return None if key is None else (key, self[key])

    def multiget(
        self,
        /,
        *key_sequence: _K,
        default: Optional[_D] = None
    ) -> list[Union[_V, _D, None]]:
        """Return a list of values corresponding to an arbitrary sequence of keys.

        If any item in key_sequence is not a valid key,
        the default value goes in the list.

        Example
        -------
        >>> d = CaseInsensitiveDict({'a': 1, 'c': 2})
        >>> d.multiget('a', 'b', 'c', default='spam')
        [1, 'spam', 2]
        >>> d
        CaseInsensitiveDict({'a': 1, 'c': 2})
        """
        # The type-hint for the default is _D rather than _V,
        # as dict.get() does not update the mapping at all.
        # Therefore the default does not need to be the same type
        # as the mapping's values.
        return [self.get(k, default) for k in key_sequence]

    def multipop(self, /, *key_sequence: _K) -> list[_V]:
        """Return a list of values corresponding to an arbitrary sequence of keys.
        Remove said keys from the mapping.

        Example
        -------
        >>> d = CaseInsensitiveDict({'a': 1, 'c': 2})
        >>> d.multipop('a', 'c')
        [1, 2]
        >>> d
        CaseInsensitiveDict({})
        """
        return [self.pop(k) for k in key_sequence]

    def multipopitem(self, n: int, /) -> list[tuple[_K, _V]]:
        """Return a list, of length `n`, of (key, value) pairs, popped from the beginning of the mapping.

        NOTE: classes inheriting from collections.abc.MutableMapping
        pop mapping items in "first-in-first-out" (FIFO) order.
        This is the opposite order to python's builtin `dict`,
        `collections.OrderedDict` and `collections.Counter`,
        all of which use "last-in-first-out" (LIFO).

        Example
        -------
        >>> d = CaseInsensitiveDict({'a': 1, 'b': 2, 'c': 3, 'd': 4})
        >>> d.multipopitem(3)
        [('a', 1), ('b', 2), ('c', 3)]
        >>> d
        CaseInsensitiveDict({'d': 4})
        """
        return [self.popitem() for _ in range(n)]

    def multisetdefault(
        self,
        /,
        *key_sequence: _K,
        default: Optional[_V] = None
    ) -> list[Optional[_V]]:
        """Return a list of values corresponding to an arbitrary sequence of keys.

        If any item in key_sequence is not a valid key,
        the default value goes in the list.

        Additionally, the mapping will be updated
        such that the key is added to the mapping,
        with this function's `default` parameter
        as the associated value.

        Example
        -------
        >>> d = CaseInsensitiveDict({'a': 1, 'c': 2})
        >>> d.multisetdefault('a', 'b', 'c', default='spam')
        [1, 'spam', 2]
        >>> d
        CaseInsensitiveDict({'a': 1, 'c': 2, 'b': 'spam'})
        """
        return [self.setdefault(k, default) for k in key_sequence] # type: ignore[arg-type]
```